# In a ConstraintLayout, determine the view my view is connected to (via ConstraintSet.TOP, for example)

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In a `ConstraintLayout`, how can I programmatically get a `View` to which my `View` is connected, provided that I have both views' ids and that I know how my `View` is connected to the other `View` (for example, `ConstraintSet.TOP`)? I want to swap two (not necessarily connected!) views in my layout.

```
void swapViews(ConstraintLayout constraintLayout, int view1ID, int view2ID) {
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

    // How do I get the "anchor" or "connectedView" of a view with a specific constraint?
    // Something like the following:
    // int anchor1 = this.findViewById(view1ID).get...(ConstraintSet.TOP);
    // int anchor2 = this.findViewById(view2ID).get...(ConstraintSet.TOP);

    constraintSet.connect(view2ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, anchor1, ConstraintSet.TOP);
    constraintSet.connect(view1ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, anchor2, ConstraintSet.TOP);
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
}
```

To be clear: There are four `View`s involved here:

- The two views I want to swap. They can, but need not be connected in any way.
- The view that my first view is connected to; this is the one I want my second view to be connected to.
- And the view that my second view is connected to; this is the one I want my first view to be connected to.

Think: In a chess board I want to swap two corners. I have their ids and I know that each of their tops are connected to some other view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the type of connection such as `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` or `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` then you can use the layout params as follows:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.viewYouAreInterestedIn);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
int topConnectionId = lp.topToTop;
```

You can look at the documentation for [ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.html) for more information.